# Return List<T> from controller to ajax in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get a list from controller upon a jquery ajax call.

But it returns an error 'Unexpected token S'.

UPDATE- Controller code is Ok. It successfully preparing the list. But ajax shows this error.

jquery ajax code-

```
var urlData = '@Url.Action("GetThanas", "AgentKycEntry")';
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: urlData,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: "{'id':'" + selectedVal + "'}",
dataType: "json",
success: function (result) {
//tasks with restul
},
error: function (request, status, error) {
alert("Request: " + request + " Status: " + status + " Error: " + error);
}
});
```

Code in controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Thana> GetThanas(int id)
    {
        return Thana.GetThanaList(id);
    }
```

UPDATE- Model code

```
   public class Thana
{

    public String ThanaId { get; set; }
    public String ThanaName { get; set; }

    public Thana() { }


    public static List<Thana> GetThanaList(Int32 districtId)
    {
        List<Thana> thanaList = new List<Thana>();


        String ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ThanaId,ThanaName From tblThanas where ThanaId<>0 And DistrictId=" + districtId + " or DistrictId=0 order By DisplayOrder ASC, ThanaName ASC ", Connection))
            {
                Connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Thana thana = new Thana();
                    thana.ThanaId = Reader["ThanaId"].ToString();
                    thana.ThanaName = Reader["ThanaName"].ToString();
                    thanaList.Add(thana);
                }
                if (!Reader.IsClosed)
                {
                    Reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }



        return thanaList;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Where do you get this error? in controller?

Comment: in ajax when getting the list. controller is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return it as Json, try this.

```
public JsonResult GetThanas(int id)
    {
        var list =  Thana.GetThanaList(id);
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

EDIT:

```
success: function (result) {
//tasks with restul
    alert(result[0].ThanaName);
},
```

Comment: I tried this. 'Unexpected token S' error has gone. But I am not getting the List of data. result= [object Object],[object Object],.....

Comment: Can I see `GetThanaList` ?

Comment: Json.parse(result) returns nothing.

Comment: You need to store it in a variable, like `var data = Json.parse(result)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40452/discussion-between-skpaul-and-wannacsharp)

Comment: ;), Why i don't see that